# jsonb_path_exists with Ef Core and Npgsql causes sql injection

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a query and two parameters. uuid and text. NpgsqlParameter is converting values into single quotes, which causes a syntax error. There must be double quotes in `jsonb_path_exists`.

code:

```
var idParam = new NpgsqlParameter("id", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid) { Value = id};
var queryParam = new NpgsqlParameter("q", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Value = q };
var sql = @"SELECT * FROM ""MyTable""
           WHERE jsonb_path_exists(""Value"",
                    '$[*] ? (@.id == @id && @.text like_regex @q flag ""i"" )')";
var rawSql = Context.MyTable.FromSqlRaw(sql, idParam, queryParam);
```

If I set the type as `NpgsqlDbType.JsonPath` it works correctly but is vulnerable to sql injection

```
var condition = $"'$[*] ? (@.id == \"{id}\"  && @.text like_regex \"{q}\"  flag \"i\" )'";
var jsonPathParam = new NpgsqlParameter("jsonPath", NpgsqlDbType.JsonPath) { Value = $"({condition})" };
```

ef core and npgsql version is 6.0.4

edit: is it possible detected  to vulnerable to sql injection of `queryParam` without run query

Comment: I would try using string concatenation in SQL. Something like `'$[*] ? (@.id == \"' || @id || '\"...` (with proper type conversions)

Comment: @GuruStron second parameter converts text if I use string concatenation. jsonb_path_exists parameter types must be jsonb_column and json_path. not text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the SQL injection here: you're the one doing string interpolation into a string which you then send as a JSONPATH parameter; PostgreSQL then parses and interprets that JSONPATH separately.

In other words, you're allowing an arbitrary **JSONPATH** to be executed, based on the variables being interpolated into the parameter (condition, id, q...). However, in no case should it be possible to "escape" the JSONPATH expression itself and cause arbitrary **SQL** to be executed.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is a bug in Npgsql, that is causing it to escape JSON path parameters incorrectly. I suggest you [file this as a bug](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues) on their Github repo.

But you can't inject column or variable names like that into a `jsonpath` anyway. You need to use [the `vars` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.17.1.1.1). This requires building a `jsonb` object of your parameters, you can do this using `jsonb_build_object` or `to_jsonb`, or you can pass it in from C#.

```cs
var idParam = new NpgsqlParameter("id", NpgsqlDbType.Uuid) { Value = id};
var queryParam = new NpgsqlParameter("q", NpgsqlDbType.Text) { Value = q };
var sql = @"
SELECT t.*
FROM MyTable AS t
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
    t.Value,
    '$[*] ? (@.id == $id && @.text like_regex $q flag ""i"")',
    jsonb_build_object('id', @id, 'q', @q)
);
";
var rawSql = Context.MyTable.FromSqlRaw(sql, idParam, queryParam);
```

Comment: I have tried but not working, again syntax error like : unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input.

Comment: See latest edit